# What's wrong with this proof of the infinity of primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

While reviewing an online textbook in abstract algebra for my website—which I'm hoping will go live by the end of the month—one of the exercises in the book inspired me to produce a simple, set theoretic proof of the infinity of primes. **But it looks wrong! I can't say why exactly—but something looks off about it!** If anyone can spot what's wrong with it, let me know, I'm too  tired to think of it now. If it's NOT wrong, well, you get to publish that for free, go ahead, I won't fight you for credit. But boy, I'd be shocked if no one ever thought of this and it's correct!

> There are countably infinite positive integers by definition. Decompose the positive integers into the following partition: the set of all primes and the set of all composite positive integers. Assume there are finitely many primes. Then there must be infinitely many composite positive integers because a union of finitely many finite sets is finite. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, each composite must be a unique product of primes. Since there is a finite number of primes, let's say $n$ primes, then there are at most $n!$ products of primes. Therefore, there must be at most n! composite positive integers. But that means the positive integers are a union of 2 finite sets and must be finite and this is a contradiction!

There **has** to be something wrong with this proof, but for the life of me I can't see what it is right now. I'm probably going to kick myself when someone points it out—it's probably something really trivial.

Any takers?

Comment: How many powers of $2$ are there?

Comment: Does anyone else find it strange that this question recieved a close vote?

Comment: @ 5xum Uh,yeah,I do-I didn't think it was THAT dumb a question!

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 The question is good and the votes for closing are really incomprehensible.

Comment: I wonder how difficult it would be to prove that given n primes, the set of products of these primes must have an asymptotic density less than 1?

Comment: @gnasher729 After my website is finished-assuming I survive my double gastrointestinal scope Friday-I'll look into the question and get back to you........

Comment: While I *love* the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, and will often use it even where weaker results (like Euclid's lemma) would do, I can't help but feel that (even if your proof were otherwise correct) using the FTA to prove the infinitude of primes would be [begging the question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

Comment: @gnasher729: That density would be $1 - PROD_i (1-p_i^{-1})$ (with PROD as the big-pi product sign) as none of the $p_i$'s have common divisors, which is less than 1 for any finite set of $p_i$'s, although it seems that $PROD_i (1-p_i^{-1})$ approaches 0 when all primes are included. This smells like Riemann hypothesis stuff. Can anyone clarify or confirm this?

Comment: ... and $p_i^{-1}$ is the (asymptotic) density of multiples of $p_i$.

Comment: I'd rather keep the proof which assumes there're finite primes, then multiplies each, and adds 1.

Comment: @MaartenHilferink: Of course... Let P be the product of the n primes. The classical proof for infinitude of primes states that P + 1 is not a product of those primes. But in reality, there are many values k for which nP + k is never a product of those primes (not just k = 1 and n = 1), so the set of composites would have density < 1 if the primes were finite.

Comment: I don't get how the OP got the number $n!$. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 38):

There **is** something wrong with your proof. You claim that since there are only $n$ primes, there are only $n!$ composite numbers, which is not true. Even a single prime, $2$ for example, produces infinitely many composites:

$$2,4,8,16,32,\dots, 2^n, \dots$$

Comment: There you go. There's one problem-I ruled out repeated products by the same prime without explicitly saying so. Told you it was trivial. I knew it simply couldn't be that easy. There are probably other problems with my "proof"-let's see what other people come up with. But that's good and quick.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 There are really no other problems. If the statement "a finite number of primes can only generate a finite number of composites" would be true, then your proof would be correct.

Comment: Well, if one would rule out repeated products, the number of composites that can be formed from $n$ distinct primes would only be $2^n-(n+1)$ and not $n!$.

Comment: @Maarten Hilferink Thanks for the clarification on that point-you're absolutely right. I always did suck at combinatorics............

Answer (score 22):

Note that $\{2^n\mid n\in\Bbb N^+\}$ is countably infinite, but it has only one prime number which is the unique prime divisor of all the numbers in this set.

Comment: Awesome, in the space of 30 seconds, a comment and two answers containing the exact same idea appeared. Nice.:)

Comment: (Faster by $7$ seconds...)

Comment: Both you guys can also clock the time difference on the comments. :-)

Comment: OK, that was funny.

Comment: @Asaf 5x's answer was faster by 7 seconds,but yours was more ELEGANT. So nyah.........lol

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: Check the time stamps (hover over the "answers X minutes ago") and you'll see that I answered about 30 seconds before 5xum did.

Comment: @Asaf My bad. Not having a good night,maybe I should quit and go to bed before I posit something embarassingly wrong...........

Answer (score 7):

The error is in stating that there are only a finite number of possible products of primes from a list of $n$ distinct primes. You are forgetting about products with repeated prime factors.

Comment: Okay, I see that this is a duplicate answer. Should have read more carefully before posting, sorry.

Comment: 3 answers basically saying the same f*** up on my part. Nice.............lol

Comment: Don't sweat it, we've all done something like this at some point. Look at it like this: you'll be aware of this pitfall in the future. :)

Comment: "This is only true if each prime could only be used once..." Even then, the number would not be $n!$

Comment: @leonbloy: Yeah. I'll modify my statement. The important thing is that OP isn't allowing for repeated factors.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct, of course, but I can't help but feel they're pussyfooting around the the *real* issue, which is that the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is about **multisets** of natural numbers.

> **Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.** For all $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$, there is a unique finite multiset of prime numbers
>   whose product is $n$.

Now let $P$ denote the set of all prime numbers. If we assume that $P$ is finite, call its cardinality $P$, then its true that $P$ has $2^n$ subsets. But it can still have *infinitely* many finite multisets. e.g.

$$\{2\}, \{2,2\}, \{2,2,2\}, \ldots$$

Comment: No, it is not true. $n!\ne 2^n$. (Or, more precisely, $2^n-1$, since presumably we do not want to include $1$, the empty product.)

Comment: (Or $2^n-n-1$ if we further require that the products result in composite numbers.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, true. So where on earth did $n!$ come from?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, actually we do want to include the empty product in the fundamental theorem, since this is the prime factorization of $1$.

Comment: (Yes, but the phrasing of the "argument", the talk of the two finite sets indicates that the poster either forgot the existence of $1$, or is deliberately excluding it.)

Comment: (Anyway, do not waste too much time on this.)

Comment: @Andres Caicedo I'm all for OCD precision in the premises, but it can be taken to absurd hieghts. I was taught 1 is niether prime nor a composite,it's the multiplicative identity of the commutative ring structure.I know that's not strictly speaking correct,of course-but for the purposes of number theory,it's a useful simplification.

Answer (score -1):

That proof appears almost deliberately confusing.

The logical proof is very simple: There are an infinite number of numbers, therefore there are an infinite number of subsets. Any unbounded subset has an infinite quantity of members.

On the other hand, I can paraphrase an old anti-proof:

There are an infinite number of numbers. But not all numbers are primes, therefore there must be a finite number of primes. Any number divided by infinity is zero, therefore there are no prime numbers.

Comment: I don't think my arguement was THAT logically flawed,peter. I never assumed there were no infinite subsets of the positive integers-a bizarre thing to assume in any event!